Movie about a high tech submarine that is sinking to the bottom of the ocean
The story is about a high tech submarine that is sinking to the bottom of the ocean. There is a monster, too. Some people have hallucinations and kill one of the other crew members.
Three people are left, one betrays the other two and manages to use an escape capsule but dies due to pressure. The other two managed to live due to being able to stabilize pressure and use a similar escape pod.
They also found some weapon, like a spear, which is kind of outdated but still functional.
I believe it came out before 2000.

Welcome to Movies & TV! I've edited your question title to make it more useful. If you feel I have misunderstood you, please feel free to [edit] it yourself. In future, please make sure your title is descriptive and that it accurately represents your question.

This sounds like a Doug McClure film

It reminds me of The Abyss but the end is different.

yeah i been looking for this movie and just wach abyss and sphere whch is have same theme.

I think you're looking for DeepStar Six from 1989.

The crew of an experimental underwater nuclear base are forced to struggle for their lives when their explorations disturb a creature who threatens to destroy their base. 

One of the crew members goes insane and starts hallucinating. When only 3 of them are left, he tries to escape in an escape pod, but it explodes (the other 2 make it out of there alive). Here's the trailer:




Ahh yeah, it seems its right :)
thanks anyway :)
